# Rust empty value for expression

Tags: rust, expression

Why am I getting an empty value in variable `a` with this code? 
Also, without the `{:?}` formatting this does not compile?

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 5;
    let mut b = 6;
    let n = 7;
    let a = b = n;
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unlike C and some other languages, the assignment expression (`b = n` here) returns `()` in Rust.

Also note that `let a = ...;` does not actually mutate `a` but instead creates a new `a` which shadows the previous one and is assigned `()`.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other languages like C, an assignment expression does not evaluate to the assigned value; assignments always evaluate to `()`.

Comment: But b will have the value of 7, what happens to a ?

Comment: Assignment expressions evaluate to `()`. `b = n` is an assignment expression. Therefore, the value of `a` is `()`.